# What are the most popular bug tracking tools?

Tags: bug-report, defect-tracking

What are the most popular bug tracking / issue tracking tools, in order of popularity?  I've been scouring the web but can't find a definitive (and ordered) list.

> I suspect that near the top of the list will be:

- FogBugz
- JIRA
- Mantis
- Trac
- BugZilla
- TFS

[Wikipedia has a really big list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems), but doesn't give you any sense of popularity.

Comment: I'm unclear as to why the popularity of certain trackers over others is of any use. A question comparing features I could understand.

Comment: What is your opinion, What's the best, What's the most popular, questions like these are FORUM related. Please close this question.

Comment: Out of scope for SQA

Comment: Agreed.  Popularity and opinion, while useful for longer discussions, is a problem for SQA.

Comment: While I don't consider it to be off-topic, I do consider it to fall under the "Not a real question" category. I wouldn't consider it answerable in its current form.

Comment: Did a little legwork... BugCam is actually a representative of a bug reporting helper tool.  This looks like a SPAM masquerading as a valid question.  I've flagged it for the moderator to investigate.

Comment: Oops. Sorry guys.  Not spam I promise.  This is something I actually need to know.  And I cant find the info anywhere.  I need to know this so that we can prioritize our development efforts by integrating first with the most popular tools.  I tecently learned about this place via a Jeff Atwood tweet and thought this would be a good way to start participating in the community here.

Comment: Ah - ok, in that case, do you want to try rewording the title/question to include why you need that information? That makes it into a different question, which I do think is on-topic. Welcome to the site btw!

Comment: @BugCam - Wouldn't that be a question for the main SO site?

For that matter, perhaps a better place to go is someplace like SQAForums which has open discussion forums for such things.

Answer (score 1):

**FogBugz**.

I've used a few and even though it sounds biased based on the stackexchange creators, I'm all about FogBugz. Not only do I use it for bug tracking, I also use it to manage projects and my team's workload. It is just so easy to use. The easier to use, the better chance bugs are going to get entered.